# Installing SQL Server 2005 Express on a server that already has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to installing SQL Server 2005 Express edition on a Windows Server 2008 where we already have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition installed.

Will that be possible?

Comment: yes, you can install any number of sql instances with different instance names

Comment: Yes but i think it must be like having 2005 installed first and upgrading it to 2008 R2 later.. But without uninstalling Native client can we install 2005 where 2008 R2 installed already?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694(v=sql.105).aspx), this configuration is supported.

You don't need to uninstall the native client for sql server 2008 R2 before installing sql server 2005.